# How to delete Open Octave 2012

Tags: 12.04, music

I installed Open Octave Studio and Midi 2012 according to the instructions from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-team/+archive/openoctave), but Midi does not recognize the jack and does not works, so I want to delete it and Studio. How can I delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you followed the PPA instructions you installed oomidi-2012 linuxsampler.

To uninstall with a terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove oomidi-2012 linuxsampler
```

To make apt-get remove any configuration files as well - use purge in place of remove.

```
sudo apt-get purge oomidi-2012 linuxsampler
```

If the install command installed other packages you might be left with those, autoremove will remove those.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto